# Javascript: How can we combine events?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to scroll one page at any scroll event but, multiple scroll events are triggered when we use mouse wheel in [my example](http://codepen.io/samdeesh/pen/XmQZGY).

I want to scroll one screen at a time when mouse or keyboard is used to scroll but the event as below is triggered multiple times for mouse wheel scroll

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();}
```

Comment: debouncing - see https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls for example. Lodash/underscore have a predefined function to do that.

Comment: @sam not sure what you mean, works fine for me. each scroll it jumps to the next header. does it jump several headers for you?

Comment: @Banana you do a very exact scrolling - precisely just to generate the event once. If you try to scroll like a real user, you'll see that the scrip gets you directly to the bottom of the page

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `setTimeout` to detect the end of scroll event and then run your code like below.

```
var t;
addEventListener('scroll', scrollEndFunc)
function scrollEndFunc(e) {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function(){
            //todo stuff
        }, 600) // wait untill 600ms, if no scroll then
                // execute actual function else cancel it.
}
```

Here is the Edit to [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyGvPR)

Comment: Tried this in my code.. not able to scroll beyond 2nd screen:(

Comment: can you plz try the above codepen once, edited the answer